# Illegal Argument Exception in @Override findAll method

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpql

I want to return a List with all the objects from de DataBase, the problem is I have two foreign keys, one can be null (almacen) and the other can't (insumo), so when I try to override the method findAll an Illegal Argument Exception is shown.

AlertaStock entity - idAlerta(int), insumo (Insumo), almacen (Almacen), stockMinimo(double), activo (boolean)

`code`
The entity atributes:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int idAlerta;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "idInsumo", nullable = false)
private Insumo insumo;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "idAlmacen")
private Almacen almacen;

@Column(name = "sotckMinimo", nullable = false)
private double stockMinimo;

@Column(columnDefinition = "boolean default true")
private Boolean activo;
```

Getters() and Setters()

`code`
The repository:

```
public interface AlertaStockBD extends JpaRepository<AlertaStock, Integer> {

    @Override
    @Query(value="SELECT x FROM AlertaStock x " +
            "INNER JOIN FETCH x.insumo " +
            "LEFT JOIN FECTH x.almacen " +
            "WHERE x.activo=1")
    List<AlertaStock> findAll();
}
```

`code` The service:

```
 public ResponseEntity<?> getAllAlertas(){

        try {
            List<AlertaStock> alertas = alertaStockBD.findAll();
            for (AlertaStock a: alertas) {
                a.getInsumo().setIdTipoInsumo(null);
            }
            return ResponseEntity.ok(alertas);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Ocurrio un problema ->" + e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: and the most important part, the **full stacktrace** is left out of this.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it, just change the service method as following:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllAlertas(){
    try {
        int idAlmacen = 0;
        List<AlertaStock> alertas = alertaStockBD.findAll();
        for (AlertaStock a: alertas) {
            a.getInsumo().setIdTipoInsumo(null);
            if (a.getAlmacen() != null) {
                Optional<Almacen> almacen = almacenBD.findById(a.getAlmacen().getIdAlmacen());
                if (almacen.isPresent()){
                    a.setAlmacen(almacen.get());
                }
            }
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(alertas);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Ocurrio un problema ->" + e);
    }
}
```